# .htaccess /subdirectory/ -> /subdirectory/index

Tags: .htaccess, indexing, subdirectory

I'm sorry if the topic with same question already exists, but I couldn't find it out.

So. My problem is, that I've a webpage in subdirectory; like..

/var/www/example/

Now, what I really need:

when I try, to get on the site from URL like: www.example.com/examplesubdir/ ; dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) isn't returning anything.

That's why I want to rewrite it from www.example.com/examplesubdir/ to www.example.com/examplesubdir/index

My current .htaccess file looks like this:

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]{18})_([A-Za-z0-9]{3,4})$ show_file.php?f=$1&t=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]{18})$ show_file.php?f=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Thank you, and appreciate any help.

Comment: Is `/examplesubdir/` a real directory? Does it have an `index.php`?

Comment: It's a subdirectory of /var/www/ < here files should appear; /var/www/example/ < this is where index.php is; in other words: /var/www/ -> www.example.com | /var/www/example/ -> www.example.com/example/

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteCond` is only applicable to next `RewriteRule` only.

Replace your `/var/www/.htaccess` code with this:

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]{18})_([A-Za-z0-9]{3,4})$ show_file.php?f=$1&t=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]{18})$ show_file.php?f=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```